# spacing in a bootstrap table using <div class="col-md-6"

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQYfS.png)

I need less spacing between each row, I used

any suggestions?

Comment: You need to provide code. Showing us a picture and asking for us to know exactly what it is you want is not helpful. Please modify this question, and provide a real working sample of your code you are using. Without that, no one can effectively answer what it is you are asking.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!